# Python - Appending value to each sublist in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, export-to-csv

I have some long datasets which I am trying to read with numpy, and append a value to each line, and output as a CSV. The eventual goal is split several measurements from the same file, so I need some way to tag each one. I came up with this:

```
def csv_test(data_file):
    data_nd = np.genfromtxt(str(data_file),
    delimiter=";",
    usecols=(-3, -2, -1),
    dtype=None)
    data = np.ndarray.tolist(data_nd)
    output = []
    sub_output = []
    sub1 = str(1)
    for i in data:
        sub_output.append(i)
        sub_output.extend(sub1)
    output.append(sub_output)
    print(output)
    x_val = 1
    x_string = str(x_val)
    filename_out = str("temp_" + x_string + ".csv")
    with open(filename_out, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for sublist in output:
            writer.writerows(sublist)
```

The problem is my output looks like this:

```
[[[0.0, -0.051, -1.525651e-07], '1', ...
```

and not like

```
[[[0.0, -0.051, -1.525651e-07, '1'] ...
```

So in the CSV writing step, the added value goes on a new line. How can I get it to append to the sublist in the list?

Sample data:

```
0;0.000000;-0.050;-6.900140e-008
0;0.100000;-0.050;-6.843410e-008
0;0.200000;-0.050;-6.778820e-008
0;0.300000;-0.050;-6.654330e-008
0;0.400000;-0.050;-6.598800e-008
0;0.500000;-0.050;-6.497330e-008
0;0.600000;-0.050;-6.415210e-008
0;0.700000;-0.050;-6.349080e-008
0;0.800000;-0.050;-6.181810e-008
0;0.900000;-0.050;-6.148080e-008
0;1.000000;-0.050;-6.032090e-008
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you should be appending the `str(1)` to `i`, not `sub_output`:

```
for i in data:
        sub_output.append(i + [sub1])
        # sub_output.extend(sub1) <-- you don't need this line.
```

Note we didn't `i.append(sub1)` because `append()` method returns `None`.  You want the full list of `i` + the single-item `list` of `sub1` appended to your `sub_output`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple here. I'm not sure what you meant about the method returning `None` though, `i.append(sub1)` seemed to give me the correct result.

Comment: `i.append(sub1)` would append it directly to `i` (the object being iterated through), but it would have no effect when you do `sub_output.append(i.append(sub1))` because `i.append()` evaluates to`None`, so you are essentially just adding a bunch of `None` into `sub_output` instead.  If however you did `i.append() first and then `sub_output.append(i)`, *then* you are actually appending the object `i` into `sub_output` which now has the increased element.

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks:

1) Don't use `.extend` here, it will split up a multicharacter string.

2) `data` is already a copy, you can use it directly, no need to create a new output

3) as the elements of `data` are mutable, all you need to do is change them in-place, which is what `.append` does. So your code after `data = data_nd.tolist()` could read:

```
for sub_list, new_element in zip(data, stuff_to_append):
    sub_list.append(new_element)
```

This will modify `data` in the way you want, and you can then write `data` to file.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yeah I realised there must be a less convoluted way to achieve the same thing. For `zip(data, stuff_to_append):`, does the `stuff_to_append` part require another list to merge?

Comment: @anothersimonharris Yes, I thought you might not want to append the same thing to every row. `stuff_to_append` is a list or tuple or array or even a generator with one elment for each row. Btw. there also are `numpy` ways of adding a column, the shortest would be `data_nd_plus_column = np.c_[data_nd, stuff_to_append]`